# sed - delete all digits in front of each instance of a dot

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to strip off the digits in front of a few IP ranges below:

```
range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;
```

I want to display the following output:

```
IP range is: 10-100
```

When I try this command:

```
echo '  range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -rn '/^\s*range/ s/.*\.([0-9]{1,3})\s*.*\.([0-9]{1,3});/IP range is: \1-\2/p'
```

I get:

```
IP range is: 1-100
```

But when I try this command

```
echo '  range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -rn '/^\s*range/ s/.*\.([0-9]{1,3})\s*.*([0-9]{1,3});/IP range is: \1-\2/p'
```

I get:

```
IP range is: 10-0
```

Am I missing something? It appears to me that sed is not looking for a space immediately after the appearance of the last octet in the first address.

Comment: `sed` is doing exactly what you instruct it to do. Due to the greedy nature of regex the `.*` in `.*([0-9]{1,3});` will match up to (and not including) the last digit before the `;` so either introduce a literal dot like in your 1st command e.g. `.*\.([0-9]{1,3});` or rethink your regex. And btw, disabling printing to explicitly print afterwards doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has to do with the greediness of `.*`.  You can still do it in `sed`, but it's easier with Perl:

```
$ echo 'range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | perl -ne 'printf("IP range is %d-%d\n", (/\.(\d+)[^.]/g))'
IP range is 10-100
```

The Perl script matches the numbers at the end of the IP addresses and returns these as two integers which are used in `printf()` to print the formatted output string.

The Perl regular expression

```
/\.(\d+)[^.]/g
```

will capture each set of digits preceded by a dot, but not followed by a dot.

---

In `sed` you don't really have to do the substitution in one go:

```
$ echo 'range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -E -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+);/\1/'
range 1.1.1.10 100

$ echo 'range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -E -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+);/\1/' -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+) /\1-/'
range 10-100

$ echo 'range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -E -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+);/\1/' -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+) /\1-/' -e 's/range/IP & is/'
IP range is 10-100
```

The final `sed` script:

```
s/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+);/\1/;   # Isolate last number in range
s/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+) /\1-/;  # Isolate first number in range, add dash
s/range/IP & is/;         # Sort out text at start
```

Which, upon inspection, can be shortened down to

```
s/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+)[^.]/-\1/g
s/range -/IP range is /
```

That is

```
$ echo 'range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' | sed -E -e 's/[^ ]*\.([0-9]+)[^.]/-\1/g' -e 's/range -/IP range is /'
IP range is 10-100
```

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed without control of the validity of the line

```
sed -E 's/.*\.(\S+)\s+.*\.(\S+);.*/IP range is: \1-\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '/^[[:blank:]]*range[[:blank:]]+/ {
    s///                 # delete the previous match, "range"
    s/;.*//
    s/[[:digit:]]+\.//g  # remove digits followed by dot
    s/[[:blank:]]+/-/
    s/^/IP range is: /
}' <<END
range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;
END
```

```
IP range is: 10-100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '   range 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.100;' |
  sed -Ene 's/^[[:blank:]]*range [0-9.]*\.([0-9]+) [0-9.]*\.([0-9]+);.*/IP range is: \1-\2/p'
IP range is: 10-100
```

in parts:

```
^[[:blank:]]*        any blanks at start of line
[0-9.]*\.            numbers and dots, ending with a dot 
([0-9]+)             capture the following numbers
[0-9.]*\.([0-9]+)    same, again
\1  and  \2          put back the captured groups

s///p                print if the substitution matched
```